# How to merge duplicates inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have three different arrays:

```
$months array looks like that:
Array ( [0] => January [1] => September [2] => September [3] => August [4] => November [5] => December [6] => March ) 

$pnames:
Array ( [0] => Furry Wheels [1] => Hanazuki [2] => Hanazuki [3] => Mighty Magisword [4] => Niko [5] => Niko [6] => Teen Titans Go! ) 

$theme_names
Array ( [0] => ANM INB [1] => ANM INB [2] => TEST NAME [3] => ANM INB [4] => ANM INB [5] => TEST NAME [6] => ANM INB )
```

I want to print it together inside `foreach`statement:

```
foreach ($months as $key => $month) {
  echo '<b>'.$month.'</b><br>'.$pnames[$key].' '.$theme_names[$key].', ';
  echo '<br><br>';
}
```

My result is:

```
January
Furry Wheels ANM INB, 

September
Hanazuki ANM INB, 

September
Hanazuki TEST NAME, 

August
Mighty Magisword ANM INB, 

November
Niko ANM INB, 

December
Niko TEST NAME, 

March
Teen Titans Go! ANM INB,
```

So my question is how I can merge same months? I want to get this:

```
January
Furry Wheels ANM INB, 

September
Hanazuki ANM INB, Hanazuki TEST NAME, 

August
Mighty Magisword ANM INB, 

November
Niko ANM INB, 

December
Niko TEST NAME, 

March
Teen Titans Go! ANM INB,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this result by using [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) on `$months` to find all the unique month names, then using [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the optional search parameter to find all the keys in the `$months` array corresponding to that month name, and then iterate over those keys, displaying the values from `$pnames` and `$theme_names`:

```
foreach (array_unique($months) as $month) {
    echo "<b>$month</b><br>";
    foreach (array_keys($months, $month) as $key) {
        echo "$pnames[$key] $theme_names[$key], ";
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

Output:

```
<b>January</b><br>FurryWheels ANMINB, <br><br>
<b>September</b><br>Hanazuki ANMINB, Hanazuki TESTNAME, <br><br>
<b>August</b><br>MightyMagisword ANMINB, <br><br>
<b>November</b><br>Niko ANMINB, <br><br>
<b>December</b><br>Niko TESTNAME, <br><br>
<b>March</b><br>TeenTitansGo! ANMINB, <br><br>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/bG7sU)